# How can one make rustfmt allow iterator adapaters on separate lines?

Tags: rust, rustfmt

In the rust [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-03-improving-our-io-project.html), the section on improving with iterators demonstrates putting iterator adapaters on a separate line like so:

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(query))
        .collect()
}
```

By default, rustfmt consolidates these to a single line. I cannot find a place in the [documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=v1.5.1&search=) to prevent this. How can one do so?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I don't see the book recommend anything about formatting style from the chapter you linked.

Comment: It's in the web page that way and I added a screenshot to show it. Also, if you copy any of the code samples with it that way then you will see that the code is on a separate line by intention. It would seem strange to have the code be something other than rust standard in the official book.

Comment: Oh I thought you were saying "the book recommends newlines between methods", but you're really saying "the book puts methods on new lines, so it must be the recommended way", right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I suppose a better verb would have been "demonstrates." I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether method chains are formatted on one line or multiple is primarily governed by the [`chain_width`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=v1.5.1&search=chain#chain_width) property:

> Maximum width of a chain to fit on one line.
>
> - Default value: 60
> - Possible values: any positive integer that is less than or equal to the value specified for max_width
> - Stable: Yes
>
> By default this option is set as a percentage of `max_width` provided by `use_small_heuristics`, but a value set directly for `chain_width` will take precedence.

rustfmt doesn't know about types, so it treats all method calls the same. You can reduce `chain_width` manually in `rustfmt.toml` to encourage it to use new lines more often.

That being said, the default width is 60, and the full expression shown here is 62 at least, so I don't know why it would format in a single line for you. When I use rustfmt with the default config it leaves the formatting exactly as shown; on new lines.

Comment: I am willing to bet I have something misconfigured. I saw that property and thought it wasn't related to that due to the width. Thanks for confirming.